# How to know if the asp.net site is accessed from a mobile device or from a system/laptop/machine(windows,mac etc)

Tags: c#, asp.net, iphone, browser, mobile-browser

I have developed a website using asp.net web developer 2010. I would like to redirect to different page if the site is accessed from mobile browser. And, different functionality for windows/mac/linux etc users.

How can I do this?

I referred some posts in some forums, and it is said that I need to depend on third party libraries.

How could I implement this without any third party libraries?

Any one Please help me out.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: Did you try checking `If Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice = True` (To check if the app is opened from a mobile device) ?

Comment: It's simply `Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice` for c#.

Comment: Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice is unreliable. E.g. it returns false for both the Samsung Galaxy Tab and Apple iPhone.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Request.Browser object properties are probably where it is at, these are all options that may be useful to you:

```
Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice
Request.Browser.MobileDeviceManufacturer
Request.Browser.MobileDeviceModel
Request.Browser.ScreenPixelsWidth
Request.Browser.SupportsXmlHttp
```

Was there a reason you wanted to avoid a 3rd party component?

We currently use a WURFL device database via 51Degrees.mobi - which works really well.

Comment: Thanks @rajbyexample!! I heard that they aren't for free. And that too I would like complete it with just a few lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use useragent in asp.net to verify the request are coming from mobile or desktop.

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            string userAgent = Request.UserAgent;
            if (userAgent.Contains("BlackBerry")
              || (userAgent.Contains("iPhone") || (userAgent.Contains("Android"))))
            {
                //add css ref to header from code behind
                HtmlLink css = new HtmlLink();
                css.Href = ResolveClientUrl("~/mobile.css");
                css.Attributes["rel"] = "stylesheet";
                css.Attributes["type"] = "text/css";
                css.Attributes["media"] = "all";
                Page.Header.Controls.Add(css);
            }
        }
```