# How to know if the site is accessed from a mobile device or not

Tags: java, scala, playframework, request

I got this question in asp.net but I am searching for `Scala` or `Java`:

[How to know if the asp.net site is accessed from a mobile device or from a system/laptop/machine(windows,mac etc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19788159/how-to-know-if-the-asp-net-site-is-accessed-from-a-mobile-device-or-from-a-syste)

Is there any way or I set it in request browser of mobile request.

```
 def check = Action { implicit request =>
     try{
       println(request.headers)
    Ok(write(Map("result"->true)))
    }catch{
      case e:Exception=>
        Ok(write(Map("result"->false)))
    }
  }
```

I tried for above request from web and iphone and android give these information

**WEB-FIREFOX**

```
ArrayBuffer((Connection,ArrayBuffer(keep-alive)), (Accept,ArrayBuffer(text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8)), (Accept-Language,ArrayBuffer(en-US,en;q=0.5)), (Accept-Encoding,ArrayBuffer(gzip, deflate)), (User-Agent,ArrayBuffer(Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0)), (Host,ArrayBuffer(14.155.235.97:9000)))
```

**WEB_CHROME**

```
ArrayBuffer((Connection,ArrayBuffer(keep-alive)), (Accept,ArrayBuffer(text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8)), (Accept-Language,ArrayBuffer(en-US,en;q=0.8)), (Accept-Encoding,ArrayBuffer(gzip,deflate,sdch)), (User-Agent,ArrayBuffer(Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.152 Safari/537.36)), (Host,ArrayBuffer(14.155.235.97:9000)))
```

**IPHONE**

```
ArrayBuffer((Connection,ArrayBuffer(keep-alive)), (Accept,ArrayBuffer(*/*)), (Accept-Language,ArrayBuffer(en-us)), (Accept-Encoding,ArrayBuffer(gzip, deflate)), (User-Agent,ArrayBuffer(WinChat/1.0 CFNetwork/672.0.8 Darwin/14.0.0)), (Host,ArrayBuffer(14.155.235.97:9000)))
```

**ANDROID**

```
ArrayBuffer((User-Agent,ArrayBuffer(Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4))), (resource,ArrayBuffer(android)), (Connection,ArrayBuffer(Keep-Alive)), (Host,ArrayBuffer(14.155.235.97:9000)))
```

Comment: Can you give more details, like what classes your using to represent the request?

Comment: @Nonos i added some code, please have a look on my updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [UADetector](http://uadetector.sourceforge.net/) to parse User-Agent header. By using  [ReadableUserAgent#getDeviceCategory](http://uadetector.sourceforge.net/modules/uadetector-core/apidocs/net/sf/uadetector/ReadableUserAgent.html#getDeviceCategory%28%29), you can detect whether it is from a smart phone or not.

It's freely available under the Apache license 2.0.

Comment: is it free to use? or it have some hidden charges?

Comment: hmm i applied it but getting some problems, if you can me check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23783746/mismatch-found-net-sf-uadetector-readableuseragent-required-nothing

Answer (score 0):

The browser information is contained in [User-Agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) field in HTTP Header. In Java to get the User Agent information from HTTPServletRequest you would do the following:

```
String userAgent=request.getHeader("User-Agent");
```

which would return something like this:

```
 Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 3_2_1 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/7B405
```

Then you can analyze the returned string to figure out if the user agent is on mobile device. There are some libraries which do that.

Comment: i updated my question, please have a look. i am getting difficulty by `USER-AGENT`