# mismatch; found : net.sf.uadetector.ReadableUserAgent required: Nothing

Tags: java, scala, caching, playframework

i am trying convert this code http://uadetector.sourceforge.net/usage.html#improve_performance in scala , but getting dificulties

```
object CachedUserAgentStringParser extends UserAgentStringParser {
  private val parser = UADetectorServiceFactory.getCachingAndUpdatingParser

  private val cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().maximumSize(100).expireAfterWrite(2, TimeUnit.HOURS)
    .build()


  override def getDataVersion(): String = parser.getDataVersion



  override def parse(userAgentString: String): ReadableUserAgent = {
    var result = cache.getIfPresent(userAgentString)
    if (result == null) {
      result = parser.parse(userAgentString)
      cache.put(userAgentString, result)
    }
    result
  }

  override def shutdown() {
    parser.shutdown()
  }

}
```

getting error type

```
 mismatch; found : net.sf.uadetector.ReadableUserAgent required: Nothing

  result = parser.parse(userAgentString)
                        ^
  cache.put(userAgentString, result)
            ^
```

Comment: Looks like you haven't specified appropriate type parameters when you created parser and cache, so compiler inferred them to Nothing.

Comment: @om-nom-nom all complete code is front of you, please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify type parameters for the `cache` variable.

```
private val cache: Cache[String, ReadableUserAgent] =
  CacheBuilder.newBuilder().maximumSize(100).expireAfterWrite(2, TimeUnit.HOURS).build()
```

Here is a compilable example: https://gist.github.com/tkawachi/2b68ca16d1b317c1d1dd